# ESP32 cam module SPI and NRF

Tags: esp32, spi

I'm trying to use nrf2401 as transmitter on ESP32-cam module.
I'm programming with Arduino IDE, but I'm not sure how to set the pins.
I know that the board has 2 SPI interfaces. The first one is for the SD card built-in module.
The second one should be free.
Those are the pins for the second SPI:
**MOSI - 13,
MISO - 12,
CLK - 14,
CS 15**

Here is my code - https://pastebin.com/qEC3JA1d

Where should I define my pins for the SPI?

Comment: There are examples in [the RF24 docs](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/docs/arduino.md)